# Oracle: select from title ok,select from view..0 rows

Tags: oracle

On my oracle db.

I have this table

```
desc titolo

 IDTITOLO                                                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(11)
 TITOLO                                                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(190 CHAR)
 GENERE                                                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(11)
 ANNO                                                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4 CHAR)
 FORMATO                                                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(11)
 DURATA                                                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(11)
 LINGUA                                                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(11)
```

and works fine

```
 select count(*) from titolo;

  COUNT(*)
----------
      2459
```

Now I create a view..

create view generale as

```
SELECT TITOLO.IDTITOLO,
    TITOLO.TITOLO,
    TITOLO.ANNO,
    GENERE.GENERE,
    DURATA.DURATA,
    FORMATO.FORMATO,
    LINGUA.LINGUA
   FROM TITOLO,
    GENERE,
    DURATA,
    FORMATO,
    LINGUA
  WHERE TITOLO.GENERE = GENERE.IDGENERE AND TITOLO.DURATA = DURATA.IDDURATA AND TITOLO.FORMATO = FORMATO.IDFORMATO AND TITOLO.LINGUA = LINGUA.IDLINGUA
  ORDER BY TITOLO.IDTITOLO;
```

But when I want to query my view..

```
select count(*) from generale;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     0


 select * from generale;

   0 rows
```

Syntax is ok,on psql works fine..on oracle return 0 rows.
Why?

Comment: are you sure that your select is returning results ?FROM TITOLO,
    GENERE,
    DURATA,
    FORMATO,
    LINGUA

Comment: And the select you've used to create the view returns ..?

Comment: Are you sure a record exists in all tables that meet the where condition?  Simply put   you don't have a single record that meets these conditions: `WHERE TITOLO.GENERE = GENERE.IDGENERE 
    AND TITOLO.DURATA = DURATA.IDDURATA 
    AND TITOLO.FORMATO = FORMATO.IDFORMATO 
    AND TITOLO.LINGUA = LINGUA.IDLINGUA`  Meaning it has a related record in all 5 tables.  Provide a record's data that you would expect to be returned. showing the relation in all tables.

Comment: Regardless of the problem, you are stating it incorrectly. You show a count from a single table and it is greater than zero. How does that imply that a join of that table to four other tables must also return something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you are using the correct columns name for join. You are using inner join for all the tables  .. this mean that if one of the condition don't mact you have no rows so you could obtain 0 rows because your join condition don't match  ..

if you need  the result also for not mathcing values you should use explicit join condition and left join

```
  SELECT TITOLO.IDTITOLO,
      TITOLO.TITOLO,
      TITOLO.ANNO,
      GENERE.GENERE,
      DURATA.DURATA,
      FORMATO.FORMATO,
      LINGUA.LINGUA
     FROM TITOLO
     LEFT JOIN GENERE ON TITOLO.GENERE = GENERE.IDGENERE
     LEFT JOIN DURATA ON TITOLO.DURATA = DURATA.IDDURATA
     LEFT JOIN FORMATO ON TITOLO.FORMATO = FORMATO.IDFORMATO
     LEFT JOIN LINGUA ON  TITOLO.LINGUA = LINGUA.IDLINGUA
    ORDER BY TITOLO.IDTITOLO;
```

Comment: if formato display a number this mean tha contain  a number ..  check for the correct columns name (and related values)

Comment: And also my view works fine.. before I put the values in incrorrect order on sql, :(

Comment: Your  comment is not clear  ..  you should  create a new question with a proper data sample,  your actual result and the expected  result  .. once you have posted  the new question  then you could comment me the link  .. so i could take a look